# Cancel DataGrid deletion

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two instances of CollectionViewSource:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="currentImages" Source="{Binding ImageFiles}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="toDeleteImages" Source="{Binding ImageFiles}" />
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

Both are bound to the same `ObservableCollection<ImageFileDetails>` (at the `ImageFiles` property of the view model):

```
// implements INPC via Fody.PropertyChanged
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class ImageFileDetails {
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool ToDelete { get; set; }
}
```

The difference between the two CollectionViewSources is in the filters:

```
(Resources("currentImages") as CollectionViewSource).Filter += (s,e) =>
    e.Accepted = !e.Item<ImageFileDetails>().ToDelete;
(Resources("toDeleteImages") as CollectionViewSource).Filter += (s, e) =>
    e.Accepted = e.Item<ImageFileDetails>().ToDelete;
```

I now have two DataGrids each bound to one of the CollectionViewSources. I want to be able to press the DELETE key on one of the DataGrids and have the item move to the other. The item should not actually be removed from the collection, but rather the `ToDelete` property should be toggled -- from `true` to `false`, and from `false` to `true`.

I tried handling the `CollectionChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` and re-adding the item which has been removed from the collection:

```
vm.ImageFiles.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => {
    if (e.Action != Remove) { return; }
    foreach (ImageFileDetails x in e.OldItems) {
        x.ToDelete = !x.ToDelete;
        vm.Imagefiles.Add(x);
    }
};
```

but this fails with:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event.'

How can I cancel the item's removal from the collection?

Comment: Why don't you handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event and handle the Delete button so that it actually don't delete the item from collection and mark the IsDeleted property to true?

Comment: @user1672994 I have to check what happens to the selection in that case; I'm checking now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `PreviewKeyDown` event; the selection moves to the next item after the CollectionViewSource refresh:

```
KeyEventHandler deleteHandler = (s, e) => {
    if (e.Key != Delete) { return; }
    if (Modifiers.HasFlag(Alt) || Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control) || Modifiers.HasFlag(Shift)) { return; }
    e.Handled = true;

    var dg = s as DataGrid;
    var ifd = dg.SelectedItem as ImageFileDetails;
    ifd.ToDelete = !ifd.ToDelete;

    //even though INPC is implemented on ImageFileDetails, the changes aren't noticed by the
    //CollectionViewSource
    cvsCurrentImages.View.Refresh();
    cvsToDeleteImages.View.Refresh();

    dg.Focus();
};
```